# group by month in sqlite

Tags: android, mysql, sql, sqlite

i have a table and i have little issue with groupby month

```
CREATE TABLE BabyData (BabyId INT, BabyName TEXT, _id INT PRIMARY KEY, Date DATE, Height TEXT, Weight TEXT);
```

from this table i want the average of weight in each month in a year

when  i am providing a date as '2011-2-2' then i want the average of weight in each month from
'2011-2-2' to '2012-2-2'

i gave like this

```
SELECT strftime('%Y',Date) AS year, 
   strftime('%m',Date) AS month, 
   Avg(Weight) As Amount 
FROM BabyData 
Group By  strftime('%Y',Date),strftime('%m',Date)
```

But i getting only 1  average

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT strftime('%m',`Date`) AS `month`,
       Avg(Weight) As `Amount `
FROM BabyData
WHERE `DATE` BETWEEN DATE('2011-2-2') 
                       AND 
                     date('2011-2-2','+12 month')
GROUP BY `Month`
```

Comment: i have some dought about strftime is this is correct:select * from USER_DATA where type ='informed' order by CAST(strftime('%m', created_date) AS INTEGER)='"+sMonth+"'